# undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass in application.less

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, less

I've just been assigned to a `rails 3.2.13` project and something with my local environment does not like the app at all even though it works fine on other people's computers. I'm also brand new to the app, so not very familiar with the structure, which makes it more frustrating. The current issue is that whenever I launch the server and go to local host, I get

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
  (in /Users/app/assets/stylesheets/application.less)
```

The error says there is a problem in the _head partial that refers to application.less

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
  <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Travel" %></title>
  <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Travel" %>">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "dashboard", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "common", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "datetimepicker", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= yield(:head) %>

  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <link href="assets/css/ie.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

and if I take the following lines out, the app renders but there is no styling which makes sense.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "dashboard", :media => "all" %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "common", :media => "all" %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min", :media => "all" %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag "datetimepicker", :media => "all" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min" %>
```

And there is no empty? method in `application.less` or anything it refers to as far as I can tell.

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
*/

@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome";


//Argo variables & Custom style
@import "argo/variables.less";
@import "argo/custom-scrollbar.less";
@import "argo/argo.less";
@import "argo/button.less";

@import "social-buttons.less";

@import "responsive.less";
@import "style.less"; // style.less should be the last to load in order to be able to overwrite default properties.

// Seems this doesn't work on production !! Try inport it inside the <head> view.
// @import "dashboard";
// @import "datetimepicker.css";
```

Gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "rails", "3.2.13"
gem "pg"

gem "nokogiri"

group :assets do
  gem "sass", "3.1.10"
  gem "sass-rails"
  gem "less-rails"  
  gem "coffee-rails", "~> 3.2.1"
  gem "uglifier", ">= 1.0.3"
  gem "quiet_assets"
end

gem "jquery-rails", "2.3.0"

gem "docx_templater"

gem 'haml', '3.1.7'

gem 'geocoder'


gem "less-rails-bootstrap", "~> 2.3.2"
gem "less-rails-fontawesome", "~> 0.4.3"
gem "therubyracer"

gem "devise", ">= 2.2.3"
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-facebook", "1.4.0"
gem "cancan", ">= 1.6.9"
gem "rolify", ">= 3.2.0"
gem "figaro", ">= 0.6.3"

gem "filepicker-rails"

gem "activeadmin"
gem "just-time-picker"
gem "meta_search",    ">= 1.1.0.pre"
gem "country-select"

gem "ckeditor"
#gem "roadie"

gem "momentjs-rails" # http://momentjs.com
```

Side note, I think there is possibly a larger problem, because I had to comment out some things in order just to get here. Because I use `rails 4.1` for my other apps, could something with homebrew or some local configurations be messing with things? Should I just do a fresh uninstall and reinstall of everything?

full trace of errors

```
sass (3.1.10) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:23:in `render'
sass (3.1.10) lib/sass/engine.rb:300:in `_render'
sass (3.1.10) lib/sass/engine.rb:247:in `render'
sass-rails (3.2.6) lib/sass/rails/compressor.rb:16:in `compress'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in `compress'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/processing.rb:243:in `block in css_compressor='
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `call'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/context.rb:193:in `block in evaluate'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `each'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/context.rb:190:in `evaluate'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `new'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:252:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:92:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:169:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/index.rb:60:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:78:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.2.2) lib/sprockets/base.rb:177:in `[]'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:126:in `asset_for'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:44:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:43:in `collect'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:43:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
app/views/layouts/_head.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts__head_html_erb___1065452930202511865_70305601381520'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:265:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:238:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:41:in `render_partial'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:27:in `render'
haml (3.1.7) lib/haml/helpers/action_view_mods.rb:13:in `render_with_haml'
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___277714497504725548_70305601320420'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_with_layout'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:45:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:18:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
/Users/MontyHackintosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:296:in `realtime'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:232:in `default_render'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:160:in `to_html'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:153:in `respond'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/responder.rb:146:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:239:in `respond_with'
devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `new'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__4105908760234858153__process_action__1733817669043599896__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:186:in `call!'
omniauth (1.2.2) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
sass (3.1.10) lib/sass/plugin/rack.rb:54:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2732989691270559818__call__1934934084652397979__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
quiet_assets (1.0.3) lib/quiet_assets.rb:23:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/MontyHackintosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/MontyHackintosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/MontyHackintosh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Update:

It has been pointed out that there could be a problem with devise and routes. Infact I had to comment out the line below `scope "/:locale", :constraints => {:locale => /[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?/} do` in order for the server to even start. If I uncomment this line the server won't start and it reads:

```
`devise_omniauth_callback': Devise does not support scoping omniauth callbacks under a dynamic segment (RuntimeError)
and you have set "/:locale/users". You can work around by passing
`skip: :omniauth_callbacks` and manually defining the routes. Here is an example:

    match "/users/auth/:provider",
      constraints: { provider: /google|facebook/ },
      to: "devise/omniauth_callbacks#passthru",
      as: :omniauth_authorize,
      via: [:get, :post]

    match "/users/auth/:action/callback",
      constraints: { action: /google|facebook/ },
      to: "devise/omniauth_callbacks",
      as: :omniauth_callback,
      via: [:get, :post]
```

Routes.rb

```
scope "/:locale", :constraints => {:locale => /[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?/} do

    root to: "dashboards#index"

    devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "users/registrations" }

    resources :dashboards

    resources :users do
      resources :travels do
        get 'cgv', :on => :member
      end
      resources :cars
      resources :rents do
        resource :payment
        get 'cgv', :on => :member
      end
    end
    resources :rents, only: [:new]
    match "/rents/check_discount" => "rents#check_discount", as: "check_discount"
    match "/rents/autocomplete_user" => "rents#autocomplete_user", as: "autocomplete_user"
    match "/rents/fill_driver_infos" => "rents#fill_driver_infos", as: "fill_driver_infos"
    resources :travels, only: [:new]

    authenticated :user do
      match "/travels", to: redirect { |p, req| "/#{p[:locale]}/users/#{req.env["warden"].user(:user).id}/travels/new" }, :as => 'travels'
    end

    unauthenticated :user do
      match '/travels(/:action)' => 'anonymous_travels', :as => 'travels'
    end

    match '/search(/:action)' => 'search', :as => 'search'

  end
```

Comment: It seems in a css file(with less extension) you have a check for empty and that variable is nil. Check that less file and either remove it or use  .try(:empty?)

Comment: in which line you have got the error?

Comment: around line 7 of application.less 7:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

Comment: @SachinPrasad my first thought too but I cannot find an extension less file with an empty? method in it.

Comment: I note you're using Devise which often trips me up with similar issues.  See this... https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2754

You should be able to confirm if it's a variation of the above problem by temporarily removing any Login link or button in your app.

Comment: Did you check all these files ("argo/variables.less";
"argo/custom-scrollbar.less";
"argo/argo.less";
"argo/button.less";
"social-buttons.less";

"responsive.less";
"style.less";) and no empty method call in them?

Comment: In fact, I notice this in your stack... `respond_with'
devise (3.2.4) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `new'    ... that makes me even more inclined to suspect the devise session new.

Comment: @SachinPrasad thats this question. and yes I did check those files

Comment: @SteveTurczyn you may be right. What do you suggest? Thank you

Comment: @SteveTurczyn I updated the question since I think it is a routes problem.

Comment: As a first step, could you upgrade to 3.2.18 ?  It's the latest stable version of 3.2.  And if the problem doesn't go away, at least we can check the trace against the https://github.com/rails/rails source code for the "3-2-stable" branch. At this point the line numbers reported don't marry up with the 3.2.18 source code.

Comment: Ah, just saw your update... you said this app was working on some colleague's machine but not on yours... have you had a chance to compare their Gemfile.lock to yours?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn that was it, in order to solve some other problems before I tried bundle update which seemed to mess everything up. If you write that as an answer. I'll mark it as correct. Thank you

Comment: Ok, done, and glad it got sorted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have gem version inconsistencies... you should compare your Gemfile.lock against your colleagues' Gemfile.lock.

If you've done a bundle update that's a likely cause of the problem.  It's a useful tool but needs to be run with "extreme caution".

http://ryanbigg.com/2011/01/why-you-should-run-bundle-update/

Cheers
Steve